# Read a zipped Stata file from URL into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to read a .zip file that includes only a `.dta` file from URL?

For example, https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/files/scfp2016s.zip contains one file: `rscfp2016.dta`, but [`pandas.read_stata`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_stata.html) doesn't work for it:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_stata('https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/files/scfp2016s.zip')
```

> ValueError: Version of given Stata file is not 104, 105, 108, 111 (Stata 7SE), 113 (Stata 8/9), 114 (Stata 10/11), 115 (Stata 12), 117 (Stata 13), or 118 (Stata 14)

[`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) supports reading zipped files if the zip only includes the csv, via the `compression` argument which defaults to inferring the compression. `read_stata` lacks this option.

I could do it by downloading and unzipping the file, then reading it, but this is messy.

```
!wget https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/files/scfp2016s.zip
!unzip scfp2016s.zip
df = pd.read_stata('rscfp2016.dta')
```

Any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_stata` accepts file-like objects, so you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/files/scfp2016s.zip'
with urlopen(url) as request:
    data = BytesIO(request.read())

with ZipFile(data) as archive:
    with archive.open(archive.namelist()[0]) as stata:
        df = pd.read_stata(stata)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I accepted the slightly briefer answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59122697/1840471.

Comment: @MaxGhenis: This answer has no extra dependencies and is more efficient by decompressing the data only on demand as Pandas reads it, rather than in two steps (decompress into memory, read from memory into Pandas using BytesIO a second time).  If terse code is your thing you can easily shorten this answer, and it will still be more efficient.

Comment: I didn't realize there would be a performance difference. Accepted yours instead.

Comment: I've added this to my `microdf` package as `read_stata_zip()`: https://github.com/MaxGhenis/microdf/pull/48. There's also a `pandas` issue to add it directly to `read_stata`: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26599.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with requests:

```
import io
import zipfile
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/files/scfp2016s.zip')                                                                                                                                             
a = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
b = a.read(a.namelist()[0]) 
pd.read_stata(io.BytesIO(b))
```